# Node Js not working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a `NodeJs` project in Visual Studio Code, but on running I'm getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:974:3
```

at line : `const { status, uuid, data: { url } } = req.body;`

This is the jsconfig.json file in root folder:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: what version of node? - you may need babel-preset packages

Comment: @DenisTsoi v4.6.0

Comment: upgrade to 6+ (const ES6 comes standard without babel i think), otherwise install babel - `npm i babel, babel-presets etc`

Comment: You can also compile these using typescript via `--allowJs` and `--outdir` by way of a **tsconfig.json** file or via the `tsc` command line. Regardless, as @DenisTsoi points out, please upgrade NodeJS. You are running an old version that doesn't feature destructuring and, incidentally, is no longer supported.

Comment: @DenisTsoi thnks, after up gradation it's working..!!

Comment: I'll add an answer - :)

Comment: @DenisTsoi In your answer, you might want to point out that the **jsconfig.json** file is not a factor here as it just influences intellisense.